# Is there a way to find which identity was used in this sign in session?

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

"A user with a customer account can sign in with multiple identities" says [azure b2c instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/user-profile-attributes). Is there an attribute or method where our app code can find out which identity the user choose to use in this session? i.e. if the user has both Microsoft and local (email) accounts set up, which one they used?

Answer (score 0):

You can judge which identity the user choose according to the `idp` claim in the id token.

For example, if the user signs in with Microsoft idp, there will be such a claim in id token: `"idp": "live.com"`.

If the user signs in with an Azure AD idp, the claim is like this: `"idp": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant id of the AAD tenant}/v2.0"`.

For a user who signs in with local account idp, the `idp` claim is not found in the token.